# How to setup my ZTE wifi router as an extender(repeater) for another ZTE router (wireless connection)

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wifi-configuration, repeater

I have posted all the settings from my router settings menu. Take a look at them.
Where do you think should I configure and what should I configure? I want to use one router as a **Repeater**. Both routers are the same. I don't want to have a wired connection between them. The model of the routers is F670L. I searched the whole web for instructions but couldn't find any. My router has very complicated settings that are hard to understand for me. I need you to tell me, where exactly and what should I configure. Note that I am an average tech guy. Don't tell me very high level instructions that I can't follow. Thanks in advance. Please help
Settings are below please see all the settings:
[First Photo of settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2AlPP.png)
[Settings 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MzoYS.png)
[settings 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D0r9U.png)
[settings 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xf72A.png)
[settings 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tYANw.png)